# MySQL updating different column...?

Tags: mysql

I've just added a new datetime column to a photos table, "processed".

I've not yet put in any code to populate this column.

When someone views a photo, I have this line:

```
dBQuery("UPDATE photos SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = ?", [$id])
```

Somehow this is actually causing "processed" to become populated with the current date/time.

If I comment it out, processed doesn't get updated.

This seems like very VERY peculiar behaviour, what could be causing this?

Comment: Maybe you have [ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html) on the field ?

Comment: Correct!  I've never even noticed that box in Navicat before but must have somehow ticked it by mistake.  Many thanks, I was about to lose my mind.